# Adding a randomised string to a $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql

So I have some code that allows users to create their own league:

```
$unique_id = $_SESSION['unique_id'];


$leaguename = $link->escape_string($_POST['league_name']);
$startdate = $link->escape_string($_POST['start_date']);
$enddate = $link->escape_string($_POST['end_date']);
$joincode = $link->escape_string( md5( rand(0,1000) ) );


//query for the highest league Number
$leagueid = $link->query("SELECT MAX(league_id) as max_league_id FROM leagues")->fetch_assoc()['max_league_id'];


//add one to the highest
$leagueid++;


//insert league data
$sql = "INSERT INTO leagues (unique_id, league_id, league_name, start_date, end_date, joincode) "
  . "VALUES ('$unique_id','$leagueid','$leaguename','$startdate','$enddate','$joincode')";

mysqli_query($link,$sql);


$joincode = $_SESSION['joincode'];

 ?>
```

How would it be possible to add the $joincode into the $_SESSION because I just keep receiving different errors when trying to define the index.

Comment: Is there something wrong with setting `league_id` to be AUTO_INCREMENT? This is why it exists.

Comment: It should be session = variable.  Not the other way around

Comment: What kind of errors? Simply settings $_SESSION['joincode'] = $joincode would solve the issue?

Comment: Also, your example do not feature `session_start()`. Even if this is obvious to say, you need it to activate session storage across your requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$joincode = $_SESSION['joincode'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION['joincode'] = $joincode;
```

This should fix it, when you also have a `session_start()` somewhere.